# Issue in displaying submenu on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap, megamenu

I am making a reactjs application with reactstrap where I have made a dropdown which consists of sub menus inside it.

I am trying to achieve the result of making the submenus display on hover over the dropdown and if there is `n` numbers of dropdown then the submenus related with the hover item needs to be displayed.

Code tried:

```
<Dropdown
  className="d-inline-block"
  onMouseOver={this.onMouseEnter}
  onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
  isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
  toggle={this.toggle}
>
  <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown1</DropdownToggle>
  <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownItem header>Submenu 1</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Submenu 1.1</DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown2</DropdownToggle>
  <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownItem header>Submenu 2</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Submenu 2.1</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Submenu 2.2</DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <br />
  <br />
  <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown3</DropdownToggle>
  <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownItem header>Submenu 3</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.1</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.2</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.3</DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

[**Click here for working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-v6-jcdivx)

Expected Result: http://supply.com/

In the above given link you could able to see the horizontal menu which on hover will display their respective submenu and I am in the need to achieve the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to separate those menus and put in a single `<Dropdown>` component.
2. And you need to set an event handler for each of them.
3. You may use `Array.prototype.map` to simplify setting handlers.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem
} from "reactstrap";

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen: -1
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

    this.menus = [
      {
        title: "Bathroom",
        submenus: [{ title: "Toilets" }, { title: "Toilet seats" }]
      },
      {
        title: "Kitchen",
        submenus: [{ title: "Farmhouse Sinks" }, { title: "Cast Iron Sinks" }]
      }
    ];
  }

  onMouseEnter(current) {
    this.setState({ dropdownOpen: current });
  }

  onMouseLeave() {
    this.setState({ dropdownOpen: -1 });
  }

  toggle() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.menus.map((menu, i) => (
          <Dropdown
            className="d-inline-block"
            onMouseOver={e => this.onMouseEnter(i)}
            onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
            isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen === i}
            toggle={this.toggle}
          >
            <DropdownToggle caret>{menu.title}</DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              {menu.submenus.map((submenu, i) => (
                <DropdownItem header>{submenu.title}</DropdownItem>
              ))}
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-v6-qsffjj

Comment: Can you create any example in stackblitz regarding the same?

Comment: Thanks for your help, How can I achieve the same result in my real application where dropdown names will be exactly like the link provided in the question http://supply.com/ .. If you help me to display the menu and sub menu exactly like that, I would much appreciate your help as I am new in reactjs, I couldn't get the picture of handling it.. My real app menus will be like that link only and i am also trying to achieve the same..

Comment: @TestUser I've edited post and stackblitz. I think you can change `menus` to get what you want.

Comment: Appreciate your help, But why by default the first dropdown is open.. It should get opened only on hover..

Comment: @TestUser default value of `state.dropdownOpen` was incorrect. i've fixed it.

Comment: For now I will accept your answer but if I had any issues in implementation will revert back..

Comment: Is it possible for you to help me in next step of the above scenario mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622206/responsive-menu-in-reactjs